# data.frame: create column by applying a function to groups of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have a data frame consisting of results from multiple runs of an experiment, each of which serves as a log, with its own ascending counter. I'd like to add another column to the data frame that has the maximum value of `iteration` for each distinct value of `experiment.num` in the sample below:

```
df <- data.frame(
     iteration = rep(1:5,5), 
     experiment.num = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5),rep(5,5)), 
     some.val=42,
     another.val=12
)
```

In this example, the extra column would look like this (as all the subsets have the same maximum for `iteration`):

```
df$max <- rep(5,25)
```

The naive solution I currently use is:

```
df$max <- sapply(df$experiment.num,function(exp.num) max(df$iteration[df$experiment.num == exp.num]))
```

I've also used `sapply(unique(df$experiment.num), function(n) c(n,max(df$iteration[df$experiment.num==n])))` to build another frame which I can then merge with the original, but both of these approaches seem more complicated than necessary.

The `experiment.num` column is a factor, so I think I might be able to exploit that to avoid iteratively doing this naive subsetting for all rows.

*Is there a better way to get a column of maximum values for subsets of a `data.frame`?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using plyr:

```
ddply(df, .(experiment.num), transform, max = max(iteration))
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `plyr`, looks like really useful package.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ave` in base R:

```
df$i_max <- with(df, ave(iteration, experiment.num, FUN=max))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way in base R:

```
within(df[order(df$experiment.num), ], 
       max <- rep(tapply(iteration, experiment.num, max), 
                  rle(experiment.num)$lengths))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `data.table`:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library("data.table")
dt <- data.table(df) #make your data frame into a data table)
dt[, pgIndexBY := .BY, by = list(experiment.num)] #this will add a new column to your data table called pgIndexBY
```